# Numpy: Interleave values of singular 1D array to 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

Given an 1D numpy array that looks liked `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` is there a built-in function to produce an interleaved 2D that looks like `[[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]`?

Shape of input: `(x,)`

Desired shape of output: `(2, x/2)`

Have been looking through the docs for numpy and have yet to come across anything that can do this with a singular array. All functions and other questions dealt with two arrays. I only have a singlular array.

Thanks :)

Comment: the array's method `np.array.reshape` with a tuple as argument

Comment: notice that `x/2` is a float and the dimension should be given as integer. use `x//2`

Comment: Got it, reshape had to be used alongside the Fortran ordering option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) in `F` order:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

out = a.reshape(2, -1, order='F')
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```